# How to define constant in SASOPTPY

Tags: python, optimization

I'm doing optimization in python3.6 using sasoptpy.My objective function looks like z=(a*p+q*b)*c. where all of these variables are columns of a data frame.
a,p,q,b are my variables & c is constant.
I'm defining a,b,p,q in following way  `va=m.add_variable(a, name='va',lb=LB2,ub=UB2)`. But not sure how to define constant c. Initially I tried `c=data['z']` & use it in my objective function
`m.set_objective((a*p+q*b)*c)` But got error message

```
WARNING: An invalid type is passed to create an Expression:
KeyError: 'CONST'
```

I also tried `c=data['z'].values` but again same error. Can you help me to correct the issue

Answer (score 0):

I replied to a similar question at SAS Communities forum, but let me carry my answer here.

Constants in sasoptpy expressions should be either Python variables, or one of the sasoptpy's abstract data types. Since you mention `c` as being a constant, I believe it is supposed to have a value in your dataframe.

Assuming you have a structure as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

you can access value of *constant* `c` as `df.at[0, 'c']`

See a full example below:

```
import pandas as pd

# Define dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

# Define model
m = so.Model(name='model1', session=None)

# Get columns
a = df['a']
b = df['b']
c = df.at[0, 'c']

# Define variables
va = m.add_variables(a.index.tolist(), name='va')
vb = m.add_variables(b.index.tolist(), name='vb')

# Set objective
obj = m.set_objective((va.mult(a) + vb.mult(b)) * c, name='obj')

# Print the objective function
print(m.get_objective())
```

This gives

```
24 * va[0] + 30 * vb[0]
```

If your dataframe object consists of multiple rows (observations), then column `c` should have a different value for each row. If so, you need a summation function for the objective.

Consider this:

```
m.set_objective(
  so.quick_sum((va[i] * a[i] + vb[i] * b[i]) * c[i] for i in df.index), name='obj')
```